# What are the default expiry time for Access Token and Refresh Token? (Django GraphQL JWT)

Tags: python, django, access-token, refresh-token, django-graphql-jwt

I use **Django GraphQL JWT**. Then, I could set **the expiry time** for **Access Token** and **Refresh Token** in **"settings.py"** as shown below:

```py
# "settings.py"

from datetime import timedelta

GRAPHQL_JWT = {
    "JWT_VERIFY_EXPIRATION": True,
    "JWT_LONG_RUNNING_REFRESH_TOKEN": True,
    "JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA": timedelta(minutes=60), # For "Access Token"
    "JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRATION_DELTA": timedelta(days=180), # For "Refresh Token"
}
```

Now, I want to ask:

What are **the default expiry time** for **Access Token** and **Refresh Token** in **Django GraphQL JWT**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The default expiry time** in **Django GraphQL JWT** are:

- **5 minutes** for [**Access Token**](https://django-graphql-jwt.domake.io/settings.html#jwt-expiration-delta):

```py
"JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA": timedelta(minutes=5)
```

- **7 days** for [**Refresh Token**](https://django-graphql-jwt.domake.io/settings.html#jwt-refresh-expiration-delta):

```py
"JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRATION_DELTA": timedelta(days=7)
```